# script tags in Express

Tags: javascript, express

I have an index.html that has a couple script tags, but they are all returning 404 errors, and I can't figure out how to fix it. Currently they are in the top directory and referenced as such. e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="./util.js"></script>`.

I tried using `require('./file.js');` but it would seem to me that this is not what I want. Would this not give me access only in the backend? It needs to be served with the html.

Comment: How have you configured the Express application to serve `index.html` and `util.js`? Are you able to request the `util.js` directly as the Address in your browser? If so, how does the URL for it and the page compare? Do they have all directories in common?

Comment: I have `app.use(express.static('orbit'));` and all of the js files are located in `./static/orbit/` but GETs to the addresses (e.g. localhost:3000/orbit/util.js) return 'Cannot GET /orbit/util.js'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `root` path that's given to [`express.static()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) is the directory that Express will begin at to match files on disk.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
```

---

That path also won't be part of the URL. It's combined with the [`req.path`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.path) in a manner similar to:

```
var rootPath = 'orbit'; // from `express.static('orbit')`

console.log(path.join(rootPath, req.path));
// 'orbit/orbit/util.js'
```

Note that `orbit` appears twice and `static` is missing, compared to the path in your comment:

```
./static/orbit/util.js
```

Or, with the path suggested above:

```
var rootPath = path.join(__dirname, 'static');

console.log(path.join(rootPath, req.path));
// "/path/to/your/application/static/orbit/util.js"

// assuming `__dirname` is `/path/to/your/application/`
```